# Issue marshmallow and nougat

Tags: android, telephonymanager

currently I have this code:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
    String networkOperator = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();
    String mcc = networkOperator.substring(0, 3);
    Log.d("TAG=>",mcc);
```

In logcat does not appear the Log.d testing in my current device samsung s7, I tested in xperia c3 (lollipop 5.1) and it works, do you know what it's going wrong?

Comment: What happened when you debugged it line by line?

Comment: Do you get any error at logcat?

Comment: If you Log.d is not showing, then presumably your permission check is failing, and the function is returning before it gets to it?

Comment: The logcat show this in red: 01-31 13:11:04.021 31916-31916/com.example.israel.localizacion2 E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
but nothing more,